# Can't create new android application project with ADT bundle for windows

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello i recently installed adt-bundle-windows-x86

but when i try to create new application i cant create it as i dont see any compiler there

see screenshot!http://gyazo.com/26bce0184baf77469215bcab1aa91fc8

p.s:- i am running 2 eclipse one is eclispe kepler another is this .. i renamed the adt bundle eclipse to eclipse2 folder all are under C:\program files . also i edited this new eclipse ini as i faced here to find the jdk path as u see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059686/jdk-error-while-running-eclipse-on-windows-7 i faced before

Comment: tried changing theme but no result ? :\

Comment: i restarted eclipse and the issue got sorted thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use any space in "Application name".

It should work.